# Devel Krumo outputting all variables in a list format and not in an expandable clickable list

Tags: 7, debugging

When I do a dpm() on an array my devel krumo output is showing a list of the variables. Previously it was in a clickable expanding list where I can hide and show the child arrays. What settings did I miss to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 3, you might encounter this problem. To fix this issue, add the following code to your template.php file.

```
function THE-THEME-NAME_status_messages($variables) {
  $display = $variables['display'];
  $output = '';

  $status_heading = array(
    'status' => t('Status message'),
    'error' => t('Error message'),
    'warning' => t('Warning message'),
  );
  foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"messages $type\">\n";
    if (!empty($status_heading[$type])) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . $status_heading[$type] . "</h2>\n";
    }
    if (count($messages) > 1) {
      $output .= " <ul>\n";
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $output .= '  <li>' . $message . "</li>\n";
      }
      $output .= " </ul>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= reset($messages);
    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```